# Inline Edit Support for Select List

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, selectlist

Scenario : Loading the select list with dynamic values from the controller and allow the inlineEdit for the user to edit the picklist.

I have to put this visualforce page in page layout visualforce page section and showing save and cancel button whenever double clicks on the field value to edit.
I have problem with giving inlineeditsupport to select list.

I tried below one

```
    <apex:outputField value="{!Case.SnoozeIntervalInHours__c}" id="HoursInterval">
         <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" 
                                                hideOnEdit="editButton,deleteButton" event="ondblclick" 
                                                changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit">
              <apex:selectList size="1"  value="{!Case.SnoozeIntervalInHours__c}" style="width:320px;"  multiselect="false">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!snoozeHours}"></apex:selectOptions>
              </apex:selectList>
        </apex:inlineEditSupport>
</apex:outputField>
```

But it is showing both outputfield value as well as input of select list.

How can I do the above scenario.

Is there any way to show the dynamic select list values whenever the user double clicks on the field(if not possible by using inlineeditsupport)

Any help is appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: I believe `inlineEdit` works with `inputFields`.

Comment: Yeah. I too searched but digging my head to give double click edit support for user

Comment: Is there any possible way to produce the same functionality?

Comment: you want to give the suggested value as picklist to a field which not picklist type?  Then i think through javascript you can achieve this. Because inlineeditsupport is only work with outputfield.

Comment: Just remove the `<apex:selectList>` tag?